# No muestra datos en GridView WebForms

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net, webforms

Tengo un inconveniente al momento de mostrar datos. En mi **localhost** siífunciona correctamente, cuando lo subo al servidor, es el problema.

Cuando busco por un intervalo de Fechas (Agosto a Setiembre), debería de darme todos los datos de dicha fecha y mostrarlas en un `gridview`, en localhost sí funciona, pero en el **hosting Plesk**, no.

**Mi codigo aspx:**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="MonthBefore" class="form-control" type="Month" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:TextBox ID="MonthAfter" class="form-control" type="Month" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:Button ID="Buscar" runat="server" Text="Buscar" class="btn btn-primary" OnClick="Buscar_Click"/>


<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"></asp:GridView>
```

**Mi codigo ASPX.CS:**

```
private readonly string str = "Data Source=#.#.#.#; Initial Catalog=DB; Persist Security Info=True; user id=User; password=Pass;";


        protected void DatosSQLporFECHAS()
        {
            SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection(str);
            SqlCommand consulta = new SqlCommand(string.Format("SELECT * FROM Clientes WHERE Fecha BETWEEN '" + Convert.ToDateTime(MonthBefore.Text) + "' AND '" + Convert.ToDateTime(MonthAfter.Text) + "'"), conexion);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(consulta);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
            conexion.Close();
        }

        protected void Buscar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DatosSQLporFECHAS();
        }
```

**Mi error es el siguiente:**

En mi localhost:

[image: localhost]

En mi servidor Plesk:

[image: Server Plesk]

En la segunda imagen, cuando le das click al boton de buscar, no muestra ningun dato.

Comment: Puedes asegurar que tu **Servidor hosting Plesk** es capaz de "resolver" o acceder al servidor de bases de datos de tu cadena de conexión?. Compruébalo pro favor.

Comment: Si, bien seguro, acabo de colocar otro query, que abarca mostrar todas las filas de una tabla, y me ha mostrado todo correctamente.

Comment: Ok, perfecto.. reviso tu pregunta.

Comment: Has probado sin el string.Format(...) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En tu Query, sustituye el `string.Format(...)` por una `@` de la siguiente manera:

```
SqlCommand consulta = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT * FROM Clientes WHERE Fecha BETWEEN '" + Convert.ToDateTime(MonthBefore.Text) + "' AND '" + Convert.ToDateTime(MonthAfter.Text) + "'", conexion);
```

Comment: Me ayudo tu comentario !
Muchas gracias

Comment: Estupendo!. Recuerda siempre valorar las respuestas que te han ayudado a solucionar tu pregunta.